# Kotlin + Gradle for JVM New Module Error in IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

My project is composed of `Kotlin/JVM + Gradle`

I'm trying to add a module

[image]

After creating the module it gives me a single files:

```
|--main-project
|----new-module
|------build.gradle.kts
|--<other-main-project-files>
```

module gradle:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.32"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}
```

It gives me an error `Unresolved reference implementation` and *I can't create kotlin/java files*
I have no issue if I use java instead of kotlin/jvm

Comment: gradle version?

Comment: @Alex.T Gradle 6.7

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem after going through Gradle logs

`kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.32"`
should be changed to
`kotlin("jvm")`

Comment: For reference, removing the version declaration will let the editor fall back to your currently supported plugin, which will lead to better editing experience. It can get very finicky if you're declaring versions.